# is there significance difference between qgis version 1.8.0 & 2 to install plugin?

Tags: qgis-plugins

I am a Qgis learner on widows xp and I want to know whether I can install semiautomatic classification plugin onto Qgis 1.8.0 in the same way for Qgis 2.  is there significance difference between  the two version in accepting the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

The way in which plugins are installed is quite similar (no significant difference from a user perspective).

However the plugin interface has changed (see https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Python_plugin_API_changes_from_18_to_20), so you will not (in general) be able to install the same plugin into both QGIS 1.8 and QGIS 2.0. You would need to find a (different) compatible version of the plugin for each version of QGIS.